# Android text input layout problems

Tags: android, list

I'm having a problem right now with text input layout, i made an error message that shows when something is wrong via setError but the problem is that the error message keeps on showing even after entering the valid information in the edit text i don't know how to call off the error message if the valid email is entered

the second problem is when i enter only the password and click register the app crashes

here's the code

```
package com.example.registerloginapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextInputLayout memail, mpassword;
    Button reg;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        memail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.text_input_email);
        mpassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.text_input_password);
        reg = findViewById(R.id.reg_button);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.register);
        String text = "Already have an account? Log in";
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan1 = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
            }
        };
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan1, 25, 31, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(ss);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
        reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = memail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mpassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    memail.setError("Email is required");
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    mpassword.setError("Password is required");
                    return;
                }
                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please add EditText Change listener as:**

```
memail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                    memail.setError(null);
                } else {
                    memail.setError("Email is required");
                }
        }
    });
```